# How to write recursion get methods in doubly linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

here is my code

```
public class LinkedListDeque<T> implements Deque {

private Node sentinel;
private int size;

private static class Node<T> {
    private T item;
    private Node pre;
    private Node next;

    public Node(T i, Node p, Node n) {
        item = i;
        pre = p;
        next = n;
    }

public LinkedListDeque() {
    size = 0;
    sentinel = new Node(null, null, null);
    sentinel.next = sentinel;
    sentinel.pre = sentinel;
}

public LinkedListDeque(T item) {
    size = 1;
    Node first = new Node(item, sentinel, sentinel);
    sentinel = new Node(null, first, first);

}

public Object getRecursive(int index) {}


}
```

I just can't figure out how to do it. I can do it in a interation way. I don't know where to start to build a recursion methods.

Comment: What have you tried already, what kind of problems do you face?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926426/recursively-insert-at-the-end-of-doubly-linked-list this should help

Answer (score 1):

```
public Node getNode(Node n, int index, int pos) {
    if (index == pos) {
       return n;
    }
    if (index > pos || n == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return getNode(n.next, index, pos++);
}
```

I believe this is what you want, and the initial call is with pos=0 and the head of the LinkedList.
I think you need to look up how recursion works though, because you failed to even attempt the problem.